# Bibliography does not appear after running tex file

Tags: bibliographies, compiling

Using article for document class the code is as following, but when I compile `pdflatex`, `bibtex` and again `pdflatex` twice the bibliography doesn't appear in the pdf file. I created a bib database called bibliography.

```
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
A
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\paragraph{Outline}
A

\section{Previous work}\label{previous work}


\section{Results}\label{results}


\section{Conclusions}\label{conclusions}


\bibliographystyle{alpha} 
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

What should I check to find out what goes wrong?

Comment: Do you have used `\cite` command inside body?

Comment: @HarishKumar I used now and it shows in the pdf file the reference that I cite. Thank you. But why does it shows in the pdf file only the references you cite? Can I make it showing all the reference I include in the bib database even if I don't cite them?

Comment: Use `\nocite{*}` if you want to show all of them.